# Text qualifier still not correctly encasing commas in my CSV upload

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, csv, ssis, etl

I have a batch of CSVs that I need to load nightly into a SQL Server database. One of the fields has commas within it. To address this, I use a double-quote as a text qualifier. Here is a sample value:

```
"97% COTTON, 3% SPANDEX / 18 GG / 32S/1JC,32S/1JC+40DSP YD / 60.0 IN / 0.0 G/M2 / PIECE DYE"
```

Despite the `"` text qualifier, this is still being read as multiple fields, not as one text field. I tried manually running this with the import/export wizard, and strangely, if I preview the CSV file, the data is correctly put into one column... but if I preview the data once I've mapped it to the target table, the value is broken into multiple fields. What gives?

Another note, if I open the file in Excel, the fields tabulate correctly.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how you've set up the import/export that leads to the broken fields?

Comment: @Quicksilver can you provide a sample data, even if only one or two rows

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have now extra double-quote within the row.

For example:

> "97% COTTON, 3% SPANDEX / 18 GG" / 32S/1JC,32S/1JC+40DSP YD / 60.0 IN / 0.0 G/M2 / PIECE DYE"

An extra double-quote will make your data messed up upon insertion.

The sample you have shown must not be the problem. Try looking at the other rows or even columns before this one.